# What is the use of setTouchExplorationPassthroughRegion() in android accessibility API?

Tags: android, accessibility, screen-readers, accessibilityservice, talkback

I am developing an Android application that uses accessibility-service, and I want to disable explore-by-touch when the user opens specific applications like Piano, Games, etc.

I read API documentation of [setTouchExplorationPassthroughRegion()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#setTouchExplorationPassthroughRegion(int,%20android.graphics.Region))

```
public void setTouchExplorationPassthroughRegion (int displayId, 
                Region region)
```

> When AccessibilityServiceInfo#FLAG_REQUEST_TOUCH_EXPLORATION_MODE is
> enabled, this function requests that touch interactions starting in
> the specified region of the screen bypass the touch explorer and go
> straight to the view hierarchy. There can only be one-touch
> exploration passthrough region per display. Requesting a new touch
> explorationpassthrough region clears the existing one. To disable this
> passthrough and return to the original behaviour, pass in an empty
> region. When
> AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REQUEST_TOUCH_EXPLORATION_MODE is
> disabled this function has no effect.

So I tried the above function in Android-11 but explore-by-touch is not getting disabled.
What can I do to disable explore-by-touch in some applications.

Note: The user might be running his own Accessibility-Service like TalkBack screen reader which also uses the Explore-By-Touch feature.

Answer (score 1):

This function is working in Android 11 and above with proper context and region

```
//Disabling explore by touch
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    setTouchExplorationPassthroughRegion(
            Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY, getRegionOfFullScreen(name_of_the_view.getContext()));
}

private Region getRegionOfFullScreen(Context context) {
    final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    final Display display;
    DisplayManager dm = (DisplayManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
    display = dm.getDisplay(Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    if (display == null) {
        return new Region();
    } else {
        display.getRealMetrics(metrics);
        return new Region(0, 0, metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to enable Explore-By-Touch if your view is not active or removed  using following code

```
//Enabling explore by touch
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
   setTouchExplorationPassthroughRegion(Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY, new Region());
}
```